# How to use dates and logical operators in Spotfire Custom Expressions

Tags: date, logic, expression, spotfire

I'm trying to add a new calculated column in Spotfire using an expression, where if a date is greater than a specified date, then the expression should return true. However, how do you tell the Custom Expression builder that you want to do this?

The syntax should be something like if `([datea] > 1-1-2014, 1, 0)`, but I am struggling what to delimit the date in the expression: I've tried double quotes, single squares, hashes (#) but with no luck.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried Date function?

> Creates a Date from a column or values. If a single argument is given, the input column can be of type String or DateTime. If a String is specified, the date must be written on a form that Spotfire can recognize and all parts of the date (year, month and day) must be present. 
>   If three integer arguments are given, then the first argument is the year, the second is the month and the third is the date in that month.
>   Example:
>   Date([Column])
>   Date(2007, 05, 17)

```
If([datea]<Date(2014,10,15),1,0)
```

Comment: Frustratingly simple. Much better than the datepart() + dubious use of AND + OR statements I was playing with!